# Data::Dumper::Simple usage

Tags: perl, data-dumper

Just interested: Is there a way to do the second form of Dumper in this following snippet?

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper::Simple;

my $data = { name => 'jim', age => 21, updated => time() };

my $timestr = localtime($data->{updated});
say Dumper($data->{updated}, $timestr);
# output:
# $data->{updated} = 1338537112;
# $timestr = 'Fri Jun  1 08:51:52 2012';

say Dumper($data->{updated}, scalar localtime($data->{updated} ));

# compiliation error:
# say (...) interpreted as function at c:\temp\test4.pl line 9.
# syntax error at c:\temp\test4.pl line 9, near "}]"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote [the docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper%3a%3aSimple):

> Do not try to call Dumper() with a subroutine in the argument list:
>
> `Dumper($foo, some_sub()); # Bad!`
>
> The filter gets confused by the parentheses. Your author was going to
>   fix this but it became apparent that there was no way that Dumper()
>   could figure out how to name the return values from the subroutines,
>   thus ensuring further breakage. So don't do that.